# ImageMagick - Convert a GIF to PDF portrait(letter) on half page using convert command

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, gif, imagemagick-convert

I have a image of dimension 1400x800, which I need to convert to a PDF so that the PDF is in in Portrait form & contains the image in top/bottom half of the page.
I need to use ImageMagick 6.4.8 2009-09-21 as that is the only available on my production server. Cannot use Ghostscript.

Image Details

```
>identify sample.gif
sample.gif GIF 1400x800 1400x800+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 29.3kb
```

I have tried all the options that I found out & nothing works. It always converts to a Landscape with the image occupying the complete page.

Here are some of the options that I tried:

```
convert -bordercolor none -border 100x100 -page Letter -density 72 sample.gif -resize 792x612\! sample.pdf

convert -bordercolor none -border 100x100 -page Letter -density 72 sample.gif -resize 612x792\! sample.pdf

convert -density 72 -size 1400x800 sample.gif -page Letter -density 72 -resize 504x288 -bordercolor none -border 11%x14% sample.pdf
```

and many such combinations, but nothing works. I use -resize 612x792 so that its letter size, but then the image also gets stretched vertically. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to, what options am I missing?

Note: I have to do this in a program so need a command based solution using convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are using this to print shipping labels.  Either way try this

```
convert -size 1700x2200 xc:white sample.gif  -geometry 1400x800+150+150  -composite -page Letter -quality 100 sample.pdf
```

Comment: This is the exact command that worked, can you please explain the options and how they work? I will anyway accept this answer.